# Creating a Pandas df from two lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two python lists in following form:

```
A = [(1,''), (1, 'ABC'),(1,''), (1, 'DEF'),(1,''), (1, 'GHI'),(1,''), (1, 'LMO'),(1,'')]
B = ['ABC', 'ghi', 'PQR']
```

(Note: A is a list of list. B is normal list.)

I want to create a pandas DF that will only contain element that are common from both the lists and the form will be:

```
DF :
A     B
ABC   ABC
GHI   ghi
```

**Please note there might be lower case- upper case and also white spaces**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
t = [v for _, v in A if v in B]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": t, "B": t})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     A    B
0  ABC  ABC
1  GHI  GHI
```

---

To handle upper/lower cases:

```py
t = [v.upper() or v.lower() for _, v in A if v.upper() or or v.lower() in B]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": t, "B": t})
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
t = [v for _, v in A if v in B]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": t, "B": t})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     A    B
0  ABC  ABC
1  GHI  GHI
```

---

To handle upper/lower cases:

```py
B = [v.upper() for v in B]
t = [v.upper() for _, v in A if v.upper() in B]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": t, "B": t})
print(df)
```

Comment: Will this handle lower case upper case as well? plus white spaces?

Comment: A slight modification of your answer did the work. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.intersect1d(np.array(A)[:,1], np.array(B))
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': a})
```

Answer (score 1):

Input data:

```
>>> dfA
   _      A
0  1
1  1    AbC
2  1
3  1    DEF
4  1
5  1  G H I
6  1
7  1    LMO
8  1

>>> dfB
     B
0  ABC
1  GHI
2  PQR
```

```
>>> pd.merge(dfA, dfB,
             left_on=dfA["A"].str.upper().str.replace(' ', ''),
             right_on=dfB["B"].str.upper().str.replace(' ', ''))[["A", "B"]]
       A    B
0    AbC  ABC
1  G H I  GHI
```

Comment: Will this handle lower case , upper case and white spaces?

Comment: @KathanVyas. Now yes :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

A = [(1,''), (1, 'ABC'),(1,''), (1, 'DEF'),(1,''), (1, 'GHI'),(1,''), (1, 'LMO'),(1,'')]
B = ['ABC', 'GHI', 'PQR']

A = [i[1] for i in A if i[1] in B]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':A})
print(df)
```

to take care about case sensitivity and spaces try this:

```
import pandas as pd

A = [(1,''), (1, 'ABC'),(1,''), (1, 'DEF'),(1,''), (1, 'GHI'),(1,''), (1, 'LMO'),(1,'')]
B = ['ABC', 'GHI', 'PQR']

A = [i[1] for i in A if i[1].lower().replace(' ', '') in [x.lower().replace(' ','') for x in B]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': A})
 print(df)
```

Comment: Will this handle lower case , upper case and white spaces?

Comment: can you add more details to get more contexts out of the answer you suggesting?

Comment: @KathanVyas yes now it does take care about all. I have updated the ans

Comment: @LinhNguyen sure. 

iterating pandas series A, and picking the element if and only if  the first element of the iterating element is present in list B

later case sensitivity and spaces is also take care off as asked by Kathan